# How do you make reliable scheduler inside nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, loops, events, scheduler

I have a Nodejs Expressjs-based service, which also should update some data inside based on a custom schedule. The schedule is simple, I don't need additional library to follow it. It's just an array with expiration DateTime values, which is being checked in a loop.

The actual problem is to make this loop reliable. Sometimes the service makes the error (strange and very rare error, I can't catch it, but it does not matter), and the result is schedule loop become broken and no events will be tracked and processed anymore.

At the same time, the Expressjs loop continues to work, so pm2 does not restart the script.

Here is how my scheduler looks like now:

```js
    async StartLoop()
    {
        let self = this;

        while (true) {
            let item_id = this.FindNewestExpired();
            if (item_id) {
                await this.RevalidateBlock(item_id);
                await this.timeout(1);
            } else {
                console.log('Nothing expired yet. Wait 10 sec...');
                await this.timeout(10000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Do I need to use any npm library to implement a self-restoring scheduler or there is a magic nodejs instruction to achieve this?

I had an idea to implement this loop as a standalone script which is tracked by pm2 and calling specific URL in my service (Linux cron simulation), but I think it's a bit overhead.

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, you show no error handling on any of your `await` statements.  If any of them rejects, you will get an unhandled rejection and your `while()` loop will stop.  To catch errors in an `await`, you should surround one or more statements with a `try/catch`.

Comment: Then, this is a bit of an odd way to write timer based code in node.js.  You are essentially polling and then checking for expired times.  You could just find the next time to expire and use `setTimeout()` to set a notification for that specific time.  After that fires, find the next time to expire and set a new `setTimeout()` for that time.  This would consume less CPU and would process the expirations much closer to their actual time.  If, at any time, you add a new expiration, you just check if it's now the soonest to expire.  If so, cancel the current timer and set a new one.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, thanks for the explanation of this another approach. The actuality of updates is not so required in this application, and another thing: it's very often that there will appear another item that needs to be updated earlier. So this approach looks really complex (and as I think) it will be less reliable. I going to try to put try/catch around these await calls as you recommended above and let's see what happens in some days! Thanks.

Comment: If you're algorithm is to just poll every 10 seconds and process all expired times then, you could just use `setInterval()` set for 10 seconds and just process all expired times.

Comment: @jfriend00 Also good approach, but it does not fit for this particular case. Processing some items can take much more time than 10 seconds and I afraid interval timer may make some mess here trying to re-call the same code again and again.

Comment: Yes, if your processing takes a long time, repeated `setTimeout()` would be better than `setInterval()`.